# Saving tab selection

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I like the tabs from [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs), but how do I save the tab selection so that it persists for the user?

Comment: You can save current tab in cookies and restore selection on load in JS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can save in localStorage the tab at selection :

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
   localStorage['selectedTab']=$(e.target).attr('href');
})
```

And restore it later with

```
var selectedTab = localStorage['selectedTab'];
if (selectedTab) $('#myTab a[href="'+selectedTab+'"]').tab('show');
```